# Add pemanent parameter to logging

Tags: python, logging, parameters, arguments

I have a Flask application that runs multiple rooms and I want to pass to my logger the room id so it will print something like this:

```
2019-03-02 01:06:10,380 [INFO] [room_id] A new user has joined
```

One solution I found was to add the parameter to the formatter and call the log functions like this:

```
'%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] [%(room)s] %(message)s'

logging.info('A new user has joined', extra={'room': room_id})
```

If possible, I would rather have something prepared so I won't have to pass this dictionary every time:

```
logging.info('A new user has joined', room_id)
```

Comment: Do you know how to define functions in Python?  You can do that here.

Comment: You mean override the built-in info, debug, etc functions with a custom class for that?

Comment: @YanivK. No, define a new function that calls `logging.info()` with the parameters you want.

Comment: What about using this to inject the room_id into the log message: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/logging/#injecting-request-information

Comment: @Barmar Oh right, Thanks! How stupid of myself to not think about this simple solution, although it is very late here.